# Extracting entity in the middle of conversation

Tags: node.js, entity, extract, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have an intent in LUIS called ChangeFlight. I can extract the date entity when user input some kind of date format initially. When the user forgets to input some date, it will ask the user to input a date.

However, I don't want to just get the results of the response, instead, I want it to extract the date entity such as the initial step. I have bot.dialog('askForDate') which asks for date from user but I am not sure how to extract the builtin date entity in the middle of the conversation.

How should I handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: Does Nicolas' answer solve your question? If you need more information on how the datetime parsing in `Prompts.time` works, the SDK uses [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono). If users' datetimes are still not being properly parsed then you may want to plug in a NLP like LUIS.ai to aid in deciphering utterances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Prompt dedicated for time resolution, it will allow a user to input a time or date/time. doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#promptstime).

For example:

```
function (session, results, next) {
    if (results.response) {
        session.dialogData.name = results.response;
        builder.Prompts.time(session, "What time would you like to set an alarm for?");
    } else {
        next();
    }
},
function (session, results) {
    if (results.response) {
        session.dialogData.time = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]);
    }
     
    // TO DO : add here what you want to do with the value
}
```